# Zoom-able/ resizable grid with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, gridview, grid

Hi i'm thinking about making midi step sequencer and I need to make a note grid/matrix that resizes/ adapts when you zoom. I've been searching for different ways of doing this but cant figure out a way that works well.

I thought about drawing cell objects made with (NSRect) but I couldn't figure out how to get the right interaction when resizing.

This is my first "biggish" OBJ-c project so please don't kill me, im still battling with the frameworks and the syntax is so foreign to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Core Animation layers to create your grid.
Take a look at Apple's Geek Game Board sample code project:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/GeekGameBoard/Introduction/Intro.html

The code shows a way to display different kinds of card/board games using [CALayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html).
The Checkers game looks to be the closest to the grid you want to create.

Comment: Awesome thank you I will have a play with the CALayer class it looks perfect for what I need.